# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined' due to page loading too quickly

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, google-analytics

I'm creating a google analytics package and occasionally I get this error if the page loads too quickly: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

I believe this is due to the page loading before the script tag in my `<head>` has a chance to run `gtag('config,...)`:

```
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-CODE-1');
    </script>
```

In my package I'm running a check to ensure the ga and gtag functions are defined first, and then a try/catch afterwards to attempt to isolate the issue:

```
  private async createTracker() {
    if(typeof ga === 'function') {
      try {
        ga('create', trackingID, 'auto', trackerName, {
          userId: user,
        });
      } catch {
        console.log('failed to create tracker');
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue with this is that it doesn't create the tracker at all if ga isn't initially defined, and thus my events aren't sent. I thought about adding an else statement to make a second attempt after a short timeout to ensure ga is then defined, but this solution has the chance to cause an infinite loop if ga is never defined. We've also tried having it loop only a set amount of times to attempt to create the tracker, but this was a messy solution, and I feel like there's a better way to go about it.

What's the best way to ensure ga is defined before creating the tracker, or to ensure that the tracker is eventually created if ga is defined later on? Ideally I'd like to avoid a solution involving the html itself or script tags within it, as we cannot rely on clients implementing these correctly

Comment: So you are saying that you expect the script to be able to be included before the GA file is added to the page? Like you are yelling for a person before they show up to the party and you expect them to respond?

Comment: @epascarello In response to your first question: Yes, it's defined in my typescript files without any errors being thrown. The error only pops up when the page is loaded in a browser. I also have ga/gtag defined via installing ```npm i -D @types/google.analytics```

Comment: The script is loaded upon page load, but seems to rarely happen faster than the ```gtag('config'...) finishes processing in the head. I'm looking for a way to circumvent that.

Comment: So is your script tag after the script tag for the library?

Comment: Yes, the script tag for google analytics is in the head, while the script for my own package is within a web component in the body.